# Trying to get property of non-object in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

In my project, user can edit his project but by updating I get an error like

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

in the controller.

I tried to get the property by using `findBy(array())`; Can I need help please ?

this is my controller:

```
public function modifyAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $userInfo = json_decode( $request->request->get("projet"));
    $eb_projet = $em->getRepository('PrManagerBundle:eb_projet')->find($userInfo->id);
    $eb_projet->setTitre($userInfo->titre);
    $eb_projet->setDescription($userInfo->description);
    $em->flush();
    return $this->returnJsonResponse($eb_projet);        
}
```

And my routing file:

```
pr_manager_modify:
    path:     /projet/modify
    defaults: { _controller: PrManagerBundle:Projet:modify}
```

Comment: Now `var_dump($userInfo)`

Comment: @u_mulder  I put the ``var_dump`` but i got the same error at the line ``$eb_projet = $em->getRepository('PrManagerBundle:eb_projet')->find($userInfo->id);``

Comment: :) the intention of adding the var_dump was to visualize for you what your $userInfo variable contains (or to share it here if that didn't answer your own question).

Comment: it should tell you, how `$userInfo` looks like, because apparently it's not an object. try to `var_dump($request->request->get('project'))` (before the json_decode) and also `echo json_last_error_msg()` directly after the json_decode line.

Comment: @Jakumi thanks for your answer but  the ``$userInfo`` returns the value NULL

Comment: ok, so that nudged you hopefully closer to the underlying issue you are facing - i.e. it does make a lot of sense that you get an error when you try to access id field from null. So your next step would be to check why your $userInfo is null when you expected it to be something else (is the data you are expecting in the request at all, are there some scenarios when it can be absent and you would need to handle that case here as well, or something completely else). You could try to dump the whole request to get more insights on what the real issue is...

Comment: @ejuhjav I found the error. It was a typing error. In the frontend I put the name : ``project`` not ``projet``.Thank you for your explanations.

Answer (score -1):

The correct syntax is `->findBy(array('key' => 'name'),array('key' => 'ASC'));`

Comment: This answer is not correct. `->find(id)` is equally "correct syntax" - doctrine provides multiple different find functions...

Comment: I never said that that was the "only" way, I just showed a solution to the problem.
In this link, you can corroborate that my solution is correct. (https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database)

Comment: Maybe you can re-read the question and the discussion (including the comment where the author says what the problem was) again? I.e. your answer most definitely was not a solution to this particular problem - it was a comment loosely connected to the question code in general which didn't provide any additional value towards actually resolving the issue. And there it was not a correct answer as mentioned (I didn't claim that your answer wouldn't be correct in functionality - just that it is incorrect as an answer to this question).